# How do I Decode this JSON in Swift 4

Tags: json, swift, swift4, decoding

I have this JSON response that i need decoded but i only need certain properties from it. I want to grab the Legend's name and the amount of kills they have on the legend. How do i struct by Legend Model in order to get the decoder to work properly?

`

```
"legends": {
    "selected": {
        "LegendName": "Pathfinder",
        "data": [
            {
                "name": "Season 5 Kills",
                "value": 757,
                "key": "kills_season_5"
            },
            {
                "name": "Kills",
                "value": 1140,
                "key": "kills"
            }
        ],
        "ImgAssets": {
            "icon": "https:\/\/api.mozambiquehe.re\/assets\/icons\/pathfinder.png",
            "banner": "https:\/\/api.mozambiquehe.re\/assets\/banners\/pathfinder.jpg"
        }
    },
    "all": {
        "Pathfinder": {
            "data": [
                {
                    "name": "Kills",
                    "value": 1140,
                    "key": "kills"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Damage",
                    "value": 257532,
                    "key": "damage"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Season 5 Kills",
                    "value": 757,
                    "key": "kills_season_5"
                }
            ],
            "ImgAssets": {
                "icon": "https:\/\/api.mozambiquehe.re\/assets\/icons\/pathfinder.png",
                "banner": "https:\/\/api.mozambiquehe.re\/assets\/banners\/pathfinder.jpg"
            }
        },
        "Wraith": {
            "data": [
                {
                    "name": "Kills",
                    "value": 269,
                    "key": "kills"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Season 5 Wins",
                    "value": 7,
                    "key": "wins_season_5"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Season 5 Kills",
                    "value": 174,
                    "key": "kills_season_5"
                }
            ],
            "ImgAssets": {
                "icon": "https:\/\/api.mozambiquehe.re\/assets\/icons\/wraith.png",
                "banner": "https:\/\/api.mozambiquehe.re\/assets\/banners\/wraith.jpg"
            }
        },
        "Octane": {
            "data": [
                {
                    "name": "Season 5 Kills",
                    "value": 106,
                    "key": "kills_season_5"
                }
            ],
            "ImgAssets": {
                "icon": "https:\/\/api.mozambiquehe.re\/assets\/icons\/octane.png",
                "banner": "https:\/\/api.mozambiquehe.re\/assets\/banners\/octane.jpg"
            }
        },
        "Wattson": {
            "ImgAssets": {
                "icon": "https:\/\/api.mozambiquehe.re\/assets\/icons\/wattson.png",
                "banner": "https:\/\/api.mozambiquehe.re\/assets\/banners\/wattson.jpg"
            }
        }
    }
},
```

}

Above is the JSON response and i want the decoder to simply just display the legends and the kills and damage they have inside their data array. I am currently having trouble accessing the "Data" array under each legend.

Comment: Have you tried searching Stackoverflow? There are a thousand similar questions.

Comment: This is only a part of JSON, or you need only a decode the inner json inside legends key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **`Codable`** to get the expected response. Use the below **models**,

```
struct Response: Codable {
    let legends: Legends
}

struct Legends: Codable {
    let all: [String:Legend]
}

struct Legend: Codable {
    let data: [LegendData]?
    
    var kills: Int {
        return self.data?.filter({$0.key.lowercased() == "kills"}).first?.value ?? 0
    }
    
    var damage: Int {
        return self.data?.filter({$0.key.lowercased() == "damage"}).first?.value ?? 0
    }
}

struct LegendData: Codable {
    let value: Int
    let key: String
}
```

Since you only need the count of `kills` and `damage` for each `Legend`, there is no need to parse everything in the *JSON*.

In the `Legend` model, I've created 2 *computed properties* `kills` and `damage`. These properties will directly return the count of kills and damage for each legend without having to write that much code everytime you access it.

Now **parse** the *JSON* `data` like so,

```
do {
    let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data)
    response.legends.all.forEach { (name,legend) in
        let kills = legend.kills
        let damage = legend.damage
        print("\(name) - Kills: \(kills), Damage: \(damage)")
    }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

**Example Output:**

```
Pathfinder - Kills: 1140, Damage: 257532
Octane - Kills: 0, Damage: 0
Wattson - Kills: 0, Damage: 0
Wraith - Kills: 269, Damage: 0
```